# Quick question about why for $p$ prime, $p\nmid a$ is need to show that $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit in $R.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Exercise 14:}$

Let $p$ be a fixed prime integer and let $R$ be the set of all rational numbers that can be written in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ with $b$ not divisible by $p.$  Prove that

$(a)$  $R$ is an integral domain caontaining $\mathbb{Z}$.  [Note $n=\frac{n}{1}].$

$(b)$  If $\frac{a}{b}\in R$ and $p\nmid a,$ then $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit in $R.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I would like to know for part $(b)$ of the above exercsie, what does the presence of prime $p\nmid a$ affect whether $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit?  This is what I did, but is not what the terse solution states.

If $p|a,$ then $a=pc$ for some unit $c,$ and $\frac{a}{p}=c, \frac{\frac{a}{p}}{b}=\frac{c}{b},$   Hence $\frac{\frac{a}{p}}{b}\frac{b}{pc}=\frac{1}{c}\neq 1.$

The solution simply states:  If $p\nmid a,$ then $\frac{b}{a}\in R.$

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's inappropriate to use colors and mathjax to format text like this. Please don't, -1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at all what you did, and how is that related to the problem. You need to prove that $\frac{a}{b}$ has a multiplicative inverse if $p\nmid a$. Well, the element $\frac{b}{a}$ is indeed an inverse. It is an element in $R$, because by assumption the denominator is not divisible by $p$.

If $p|a$ then there is no inverse. Indeed, assume we have $\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}=1$ where $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}$ are written in a form where the denominators are not divisible by $p$. Then $ac=bd$. Since $p|a$, it follows that $p|bd$, and so $p|b$ or $p|d$, a contradiction.

Comment: but isn't that enough that $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$ in order for $\frac{a}{b}$ to have an inverse?  I just don't understand why $p$ prime needs to be invovled here..  It feels like $p$ is something extra that is not necessary.

Comment: @Seth No, I explained in the second paragraph why for example $\frac{p}{1}$ doesn't have an inverse. $R$ is not the ring of rational numbers, it is a subring which consists of very specific rational numbers. (such that can be written in a form where the denominator is not divisible by $p$)

Comment: ah ok ok. Thank you for the clarifactions.